# Writing dictionary that contains some scalar and some array values to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is similar to the following example:

```
dict = {key1: value1, key2: [arrayValue1, arrayValue2]}
```

I would like to write it to a CSV file, in this format:

```
key1     key2
value1   arrayValue1
         arrayValue2
```

Searching through similar questions I found the way to write the dictionary if all of the values are either scalar or array, but I haven't found the answer if the values are a combination of the two.

I have the following code for writing scalar values:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:  
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(dict)
```

And the following code for writing array values:

```
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(dict.keys())
        writer.writerows(zip(*dict.values()))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `DATA['key2'] = '\n'.join(DATA['key2'])` before `w.writerow(DATA)`

Comment: BTW those are lists, not arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't declare variables named `dict` as this stands for a Python built-in function that we'll use here. Rather, use something such as `dct`.

```
dct = {"key1": "value1", "key2": ["arrayValue1", "arrayValue2"]}
```

First, put every scalar inside an array.

```
myvalues = [ x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in dct.values() ]
```

Next, make every array as long as the largest array. Fill the gaps with empty strings.

```
maxlength = max([len(x) for x in myvalues])
myvalues = [ x + (maxlength - len(x))*[""] for x in myvalues ]
```

Now you can just rebuild your dictionary, convert it into a pandas DataFrame and save this DataFrame as a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
dct = dict(zip(dct.keys(), myvalues))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)
df.to_csv("your_filename_goes_here.csv", index=False)
```

And then you have your file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating a more regular dictionary where all keys have equal size lists.

```
 outputDict = { key: value if isinstance(value,list) else [value] for key,value in dict.items() }
 padding = [""] * max( len(value) for value in outputDict.values() )
 outputDict = { key: (value + padding)[:len(padding)] for key,value in outputDict.items() }
 writer.writerow(outputDict.keys())
 writer.writerows(zip(*outputDict.values()))
```